# Restarting app server using AWS API

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

I need to restart my AWS app server, for this I tried to use AWS API and have done the following:

1) Used the aws java sdk maven repository

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
         <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-elasticbeanstalk</artifactId>
             <version>1.11.86</version>
   </dependency>
```

2) Used the below code segment:

```
   AWSElasticBeanstalk client = new AWSElasticBeanstalkClient();
   RestartAppServerRequest request = new RestartAppServerRequest()
                                .withEnvironmentId("<myEnvId>")
                            .withEnvironmentName("<myEnvName>");
   RestartAppServerResult response = client.restartAppServer(request);
```

I get the below error:

> com.amazonaws.services.elasticbeanstalk.model.AWSElasticBeanstalkException: No Environment found for EnvironmentId = ''. (Service: AWSElasticBeanstalk; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: 4d025449-ed00-11e6-8405-4d5eb8e5ecd9)

The `<myEnvId>` and `<myEnvName>` are correct as they are taken from the AWS dashboard.

I also tried including the `aws.accessKeyId` and `aws.secretKey` to java system properties. Still I get the same error.

Is there something I am missing or doing wrong? Please advice.

Thanks,

Clyde

Comment: habe you configured the region correctly in the sdk?

Comment: thanks @hellomichibye. no, i didnt do that. where do i set that at?

Comment: @hellomichibye, I found that you can set the region. However although the code compiles when run it says that AWSElasticBeanstalkClient is now depreciated and I need to use AwsClientBuilder.withCredentials(AWSCredentialsProvider) instead.

But I am given the below error error at AwsClientBuilder.withCredentials:
 The method withCredentials(AWSCredentialsProvider) in the type AwsClientBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (AWSCredentials)

What do you think the issue is?

Thanks.

Comment: This is my code segment:
 AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new AWSCredentialsProviderChain(new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(),new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider(),new SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider()
                    );;
 AWSElasticBeanstalk client = AwsClientBuilder.withCredentials(credentialsProvider.getCredentials()); 
 RestartAppServerRequest request = new RestartAppServerRequest()
   .withEnvironmentId("e-srdh6yr3mz")
          .withEnvironmentName("sellingtozebras-staging-env");
 RestartAppServerResult response = client.restartAppServer(request);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all who posted. I manged to solve the issue. The code segment used is as follows:

```
    AWSElasticBeanstalk client = new AWSElasticBeanstalkClient(); 
    client.setEndpoint(<set your endpoint>);
    RestartAppServerRequest request = new RestartAppServerRequest()
            .withEnvironmentId(<set your env id>)
            .withEnvironmentName(<set your env name>);
    RestartAppServerResult response = client.restartAppServer(request);
```

This worked find.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to configure the region. For example to configure the region to us-west-2 you would use the following code:

```
AWSElasticBeanstalk client = new AWSElasticBeanstalkClient();
client.configureRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2);
```

Comment: Thanks. I managed to set the region as you mentioned.

However although the code compiles when run it says that AWSElasticBeanstalkClient is now depreciated and I need to use AwsClientBuilder.withCredentials(AWSCredentialsProvider) instead.

Is there anything I am missing.

Thanks. Clyde

Comment: It still works doesn't it? You just need to look into using the AwsClientBuilder for future compatibility purposes.